# Is it possible to dynamically update parametrized fixture's params?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run the same set of tests on multiple fixture values, but I don't want to "hardcode" those values in fixture definition.

My use-case is an interface with multiple implementations and I want to run the same tests on each implementation.

For example, my_code.py

```py
class Interface:
   def method():
      pass

class Impl1(Interface):
   def method():
      return 1

class Impl2(Interface):
   def method():
      return 2
```

test_interface.py:

```py
def test_method(instance: Interface):
    assert type(instance.method()) == int
```

test_impl1.py

```py
from my_code import Impl1
@pytest.fixture
def instance():
    return Impl1()
```

test_impl2.py

```py
from my_code import Impl2
@pytest.fixture
def instance():
    return Impl2()
```

Obviously this code does not work (because fixture "instance" is not found). I can write something like this in conftest.py

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=[Impl1(), Impl2()])
def instance(request):
   return requst.param
```

but I want to be able to run test_impl1.py to only test Impl1. Also, if I ever going to write Impl3, I dont want to change conftest.py, I want to just add simple test_impl3.py
And what if my implementation is in completely other package?

In short, I want to reuse my tests for each value from a list of fixtures, but I want to change this list of fixtures in runtime (e.g. depending on available implementations)

Comment: Make a helper function from that `test_method`, the same one but without test_ prefix, and create test_method_1 that calls it with `Impl1()` argument, and so on.

Comment: Actually I have 60+ tests. Moreover, I want to be able to add tests to test_impl.py, so that those tests automatically were added to each implementation test set

Comment: You can use `pytest_generate_tests` hook to pass in dynamically generated values to the fixture. This hook gets called before test collection and execution. You can write some custom code in it e.g. based on the command line args and construct the list of params to parametrize the fixture. Take a look at [this example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#deferring-the-setup-of-parametrized-resources) where the db fixture is parametrized with a list. The list in example is hardcoded but you could put in some logic to build it dynamically.

Comment: Finally worked this out, posted as an answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked this out, however not sure if this is reliable solution.
in `test/common/test_common.py` I put my tests:

```py
def test_method(instance: Interface):
    assert type(instance.method()) == int
```

in `tests/common/conftest.py` I have interesting stuff:

```py
THIS_PACKAGE = 'tests/common/'

def create_instance_hooks(meta_fixture, name):
    tests_node_id = os.path.join(THIS_PACKAGE, '{}.py'.format(name))

    def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
        split = item.nodeid.split('::')
        filename, *test_name = split
        if filename == tests_node_id and 'instance' in item.fixturenames:
            func_name = meta_fixture.__name__
            meta = tuple(item.session._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs[func_name])
            item._request._arg2fixturedefs['instance'] = meta

    @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
    def pytest_collect_file(path, parent):
        outcome = yield
        result = outcome.get_result()

        if parent.parent is None:
            result.append(
                DoctestModule(os.path.join(parent.fspath, THIS_PACKAGE, 'conftest.py'), parent,
                              nodeid=os.path.join(THIS_PACKAGE, '{}_conf.py'.format(name))))

            result.append(Module(os.path.join(parent.fspath, THIS_PACKAGE, 'test_common.py'), parent,
                                 nodeid=tests_node_id))

    return pytest_runtest_protocol, pytest_collect_file
```

and in `tests/impl1/conftest.py` I have

```py
@pytest.fixture
def impl1_instance():
    return Impl1()


pytest_runtest_protocol, pytest_collect_file = create_instance_hooks(impl1_instance, 'impl1')
```

and in `tests/impl2/conftest.py` I have

```py
@pytest.fixture
def impl2_instance():
    return Impl2()


pytest_runtest_protocol, pytest_collect_file = create_instance_hooks(impl2_instance, 'impl2')
```

So basically when `tests/implN` tests are collected, `pytest_collect_file` hook adds tests from `tests/common/test_common.py`
and then when they are run, `pytest_runtest_protocol` hook adds `implN_instance` fixture as instance fixture. So, if I run just impl1 or impl2, one set of tests are run, and if I run just pytest tests, there are two sets of tests with appropriate fixtures